# MVC Laravel - Mejor práctica para ciertos casos

Tags: php, laravel, mvc, controller, model

Soy algo nuevo en Laravel, y me molesta que tenga tantas opciones y creo que no le saco su mejor fruto. Entonces vengo a presentar una parte de mi proyecto que me toca hacer, y quiero aprovechar para hacerla de la mejor forma, Explico :

Tengo un proyecto con login de usuarios y varias cosas extras. Pero esta vez se le agregara al usuario una wallet/cartera virtual. Lo que normalmente haria es poner todo en el controlador, usando Eloquent claro para las consultas de la wallet, pero hay ciertas funciones, que no se donde se pondrian, pondre un ejemplo :

```
class WalletController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        //Reviso si el usuario conectado no tiene wallet
        $wallet = Wallet::find(Auth::user()->id);
        if(is_null($wallet))
        {
            $wallet = Wallet::create([
                'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
                'address' => funcionQueCreaTextoAlAzarConID(Auth::user()->id)
            ]);
        }
        return view('wallet',$wallet);
    }
}
```

Mi primer problema, es no saber donde poner "funcionQueCreaTextoAlAzarConID(Auth::user()->id)" esa funcion.

Mi segundo problema es como haria para simplificar mas ese codigo, en caso de quererlo usar varias veces.

Tener algo ejemplo :

```
class WalletController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        //Obtener la wallet del usuario, si no tiene, crearle una

        $wallet = obtenerOCrearWalletUsuarioSiNoTiene(Auth::user()->id);

        return view('wallet',$wallet);
    }
}
```

Se que laravel tiene cosas como los servicios, y hasta los helpers, pero me preocupa no darle bien el uso a las cosas. Por eso presentaba este caso, que me aclararia muchas cosas

Comment: Lo que podrías hacer es que si la función la vas a usar muchas veces podrías crear un "BaseController" el cual extienda de "Controller" en esta clase pones todos los metodos que usaras constantemente y cuando quieras crear un nuevo controlador lo extiendes de este "BaseController". Disculpas por no poner un ejemplo pero ando en el celular.

Comment: Como indicas, los helpers son ideales para cosas como esas, ahora si no sabes como hacerla solo dilo para poder darte la ayuda correspodiente